# When loading data from Oracle DB, column values are coming as substring

Tags: oracle, go, substring

This is my Oracle table:

```
Table Name: Employee
----------------------
Emp_Id    Emp_Name

12345     Sussane

54321     Alex
```

The following `SELECT` query is getting correct results in SQL Developer:

```
SELECT Emp_Id,Emp_Name from Employee;
```

And the result of that query:

```
12345     Sussane

54321     Alex
```

But when I am loading this table using GoLang, sometimes (not always), I am getting results like below:

Run 1:

```
1     Sussane

5     Alex
```

Run 2:

```
12     Sussane

54     Alex
```

My code:

```
    rows, dbQueryErr:= db.QueryContext(ctx,"SELECT Emp_Id,Emp_Name from Employee")
    if dbQueryErr != nil{
            return nil,dbQueryErr
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    cols, readColErr := rows.Columns()
    if readColErr!= nil{
            rows.Close()
            return nil,readColErr
    }

    for rows.Next() {

            columns := make([]interface{}, len(cols))
            columnPointers := make([]interface{}, len(cols))
            for i, _ := range columns {
                    columnPointers[i] =&columns[i]
            }

            if err := rows.Scan(columnPointers...); err != nil {
                    logger.Println("Main Data Query Scan Err:", err)
                    return nil, err
            }
            m := make(map[string]interface{})
            for i, colname := range cols {
                    val := columnPointers[i].(*interface{})
                    m[colname] = *val
            }
                            var sKeys string=keyColumns[0]
            mapString := make(map[string]string)
            for key,value := range m{
                    strKey := fmt.Sprintf("%v", key)
                    strValue := fmt.Sprintf("%v", value)
                    mapString[strKey] = strValue
            }
            fmt.Println("m--->", m)
    }
```

Note: at `m--->`, I am getting incorrect results.